# SQL statement selecting rows from a table dependent on information from another table

Tags: sql

I have two different tables in a database, differing in number of columns. Now, I want to select a number of rows from the first table dependent on some variable (for example that the first column should have the value 1). However, I would also like to use information from my other table to select rows from my first table.

In my specific case, both `table1` and `table2`contains the columns `Group` and `Person`. Table1 specify each person once, and declares what group he or she belongs to. However, people can also be part of secondary groups, which are listed in `table2`. That is, in `table2`, a person can be listed again with a new group number.

I would like to write an SQL statement where I select persons (that is, rows) from `table1` (since I have more information about the persons in this table) that are members of a certain group, `x`. However, since a person can belong to several groups, I need to look through `table2` as well, somehow.

How can I write this SQL statement?

Comment: It sounds like you need to refactor your schema.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would absolutely love to, but I'm working with a database that is being used by another program that I don't manage, so I can make zero changes :(

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.person_id,t1.group_id 
from table1
union all
select t2.person_id,t2.group_id
from table2
```

this will give you one table

```
person group
person1 group1
person1 group2
person2 group3
```

no matter what tables they belong to.

This architecture seems silly however if the same data is in both tables.

Comment: I will need the data from `table1` (for example the persons gender and birth date, which are not contained in `table2`), so I guess this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of identifier in both tables - like a candidate key. 
When you do your select you need to join the tables, example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM Table1 table_name1
INNER JOIN Table2 table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
WHERE table_name1.person = table_name2.person
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, this query below will get you a person's details where the person is a member of a group 'X' and that relationship between person and that particular group 'X'is coming from a record maintained in either `table1` or `table2`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Person = t2.Person
WHERE t1.Person = 'Y'
AND (t1.Group = 'X' OR t2.Group = 'X')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` clause to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

Let's look at a selection in this example:

SELECT 
       table1.user_name, 
       table2.group_name, 
       table1.address 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.UserID = table2.ID;